# Difference between computer names and dnshostname in PowerShell cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, remote-access

I write script that need to be used in different active directory forests.

In one forest I am able to use simple computer names that are the same as the computer samaccountname value.

`mycomputername`

In another forest I have to use dnshostnames that are normally shaped like 
`mycomputername.some.domain.path.com`

Is this a forest setting and how can I identify this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a remote host by name you must be able to resolve the name (be it a hostname or FQDN) to an IP address. Whether you can resolve a hostname or need an FQDN depends on the search domains that are configured (or not configured) on a computer's network adapter.